# Golang web scraper NTLM authentication

Tags: authentication, go, web-scraping, ntlm

A Golang web scraper needs to extract information from a webpage that is NTLM-authenticated.

Having a valid username & password, how can the web scraper perform the NTLM 4-way handshake with the server in order to gain access to the protected webpage behind?

```
url, username, password := "http://www.some-website.com", "admin", "12345"

client := &http.Client{}
req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", url, nil)
req.Header.Set("Authorization", "NTLM")
res, _ := client.Do(req)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a package like [`Azure/go-ntlmssp`](https://github.com/Azure/go-ntlmssp) to authenticate before you start scraping.

```
url, username, password := "http://www.some-website.com", "admin", "12345"

client := &http.Client{
    Transport: ntlmssp.Negotiator{
        RoundTripper:&http.Transport{},
    },
}

req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", url, nil)
req.SetBasicAuth(username, password)

res, _ := client.Do(req)
```

Comment: @John i have tried the same code but it did not work for me, now here the thing is sometimes the authentication happens and sometimes not, please suggest

Comment: @VijayKumar I have not provided error handling in the example code. Try checking the errors to see what's wrong.

Comment: @JohnSPerayil error says 401 unauthorized, its an https domain. Do we need to modify anything for an https domain

Comment: @VijayKumar HTTPS shouldn't be a problem, besides the server is returning Unauthorised. But would need more details to debug the issue since you said it happens only sometimes.

This comment box is not the right place to discuss it are so create a question on SO with more details or create a room on https://chat.stackoverflow.com and invite me so that we can discuss it.

Comment: @JohnSPerayil i have created a group and invited you there, please join in