# Windows NTLM authentication using Golang

Tags: go, windows-authentication, ntlm

Need to make http call using golang client (net/http)  which requires integrated windows authentication (NTLM) ([similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40488583/golang-web-scraper-ntlm-authentication/44832963)  ) its not working.. - i am not what am missing below is the code that i use.. (package used -   ntlmssp "github.com/Azure/go-ntlmssp")

```
client := &http.Client{
    Transport: ntlmssp.Negotiator{
        RoundTripper: &http.Transport{},
    },
}

req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", url1, nil)

req.SetBasicAuth("login", "password") 

res, err := client.Do(req)
```

I get the error the following response ..

```
{401 Unauthorized 401 HTTP/1.1 1 1 map[Content-Type:[text/html] Server:[Microsoft-IIS/8.5] Www-Authenticate:[NTLM Negotiate]
```

Appears to work when i run against a local webserver which has windows auth enabled... differene i notice is in the IIS version - not sure how it impacts NTLM...

```
200 OK 200 HTTP/1.1 1 1 map[Content-Type:[text/html] Accept-Ranges:[bytes] Server:[Microsoft-IIS/10.0] Persistent-Auth:[true] L
```

In addition.. when i notice the NTLM handshake - this is what i see (not very familiar  with NTLM handshake/what it would imply... ) so not sure if this means anything...

When it works the authorization tags to Negotiate [image: When it works the authorization tags to Negotiate]

but when it fails the authorization tags to NTLM [image: but when it fails the authorization tags to NTLM]

Comment: What's the difference between the sites it works with and those where it does not?

Comment: corrected myself - it does not work with any (had performed a bad test )

Comment: ok here is an update... it does actually work at times... i setup a local site which requires authentication  the difference i see is the IIS version   
   {401 Unauthorized 401 HTTP/1.1 1 1 map[Content-Type:[text/html] Server:[Microsoft-IIS/8.5] Www-Authenticate:[NTLM Negotiate] Date:[Thu, 29 Jun 2017 21:25:13 GMT]   vs   200 OK 200 HTTP/1.1 1 1 map[Content-Type:[text/html] Accept-Ranges:[bytes] Server:[Microsoft-IIS/10.0] Persistent-Auth:[true] L

Comment: If you look at the readme for that library, there are some fairly specific circumstances under which it's designed to work, that may or may not be the issue.

Comment: thank.. am wondering the same... but i could not see/understand what is different.. i did figure out the Authorization - NTLM... but thats jsut about how to configure IIS - i am guessing NTLM version issue... anywayz i'll keep digging.. Thanks again @Adrian for your  feedback!!!

Comment: Did this every get resolved? I'd be interested in seeing the answer as we're about to implement a Go web server with Windows Authentication.

Comment: No this did not get resolved, but this was more about a go client (cli) making a call to rest API using Windows authentication

Comment: @Vikram did anyone got the answer for this, even i need to do NTLM authentication over https

Comment: Do you need to do this with the credentials of the current user? If so, you can do it with COM: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42816600/windows-system-credentials-in-go-http-ntlm-requests

Comment: I solved this problem by disabling the “extended protection” on IIS